# Swift Crashing: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)"

Tags: swift, uikit, swift5

Hello I'm crashing due to this error
I know that the cause is a unaccessible memory but I don't really know how to fix this error and I don't know what's exactly causing it

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

Here's an screenshot of the code that's causing the error (the catch)

[image]

Comment: enable zombies (like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode) and see what it finds. PPOssibly something is deallocated by the time you are trying to access it (maybe `self`)

Answer (score 0):

It was an error in another function (objective C function) that used await to call the signUserIn() function

The mistake was that I've tried to call the objc function as async